# Is it possible to generate SQL `OR` clauses by using scope methods?

Tags: sql, ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, squeel

I am using Ruby on Rails 3.2.2 and the Squeel gem. I would like to know if there is a way to use more that one scope method so to generate SQL queries with `OR` clauses related to those scope method SQL conditions. That is, I have:

```
class Article < ActiveRecord::Base
  def self.scope_method_1
    ... # scope_method_1 SQL conditions
  end

  def self.scope_method_2
    ... # scope_method_2 SQL conditions
  end

  def self.scope_method_combination
    # I am looking for something like
    #
    # where{scope_method_1 | scope_method_2} # Note: The '|' means the SQL 'OR' clause in the Squeel context
    #
    # so to generate the following SQL query:
    #
    # SELECT FROM articles WHERE <scope_method_1 SQL conditions> OR <scope_method_2 SQL conditions>
  end
end
```

Is it possible to generate SQL `OR` clauses with scope methods (by using or not the Squeel gem)?

Comment: Would it not suffice to write a scope_method_3 with the OR sql statement written into it?

Comment: @Trip - I think the `scope_method_3` you are thinking about could not follow the DRY (Don't Repeat Yourself) principle.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We have been discussing this on the [squeel issue tracker](https://github.com/ernie/squeel/issues/142) and the basic answer seems to be no.   At least not with scopes; but if you convert the scopes into sifters you can.

Comment: I agree, I think it has to do with keeping track of table names when doing joins, scopes just don't provide enough info to keep the algebra straight...